# Sitecore Web forms for marketers 2.4 file upload on content delivery server error (WFFM)

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Web Form For Marketers 2.4 question

Situation: I'm getting technical error on a form with file upload field when form is submitted from content delivery server. Sofar I could identify that the problem happens on CD servers because there is no reference to master database. I appreciate that WFFM documenation says that FileUpload field works with master database, but at the same the documentation also mentions possibility to use "remoteWfmService". But even after configuring web service I see similar "null reference exception" in logs. Is it possible to make WFFM work without adding reference to Master database to configuration files?

Comment: Did you add `remoteWfmService` to your connection strings? Also have a look here: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/08/web-forms-file-upload-2-exceptions.html

Comment: thanks Jammy, it works now. The first thing I did to test my theory about reference to master database was to change "master" to "web" in forms.config, but I thought that it would break something else and was looking for a proper solution. This was the missing bit. However, I must say that I still don't see the uploaded file in Media folder - I'll dig further into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have an entry in your connectionStrings.config called `remoteWfmService` on your CD server. It should look something similar to this:

```
<add name="remoteWfmService" connectionString="url=http://[masterserver]/sitecore%20modules/shell/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Staging/WfmService.asmx;user=[domain\username];password=[password];timeout=60000" />
```

See section 2.11.1 of the [Web Forms for Marketers reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v21_reference-a4.pdf).

You also need to change the following setting  in `/App_Config/Include/forms.config` file.

```
<!-- Sets the name of the master database  -->
<setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="web"/>
```

This isn't mentioned in the reference guide for some reason, but is looks like this same error as on [this post](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/08/web-forms-file-upload-2-exceptions.html) by Alex Shyba.

Comment: We are using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) +
Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523 . in CD server when I add "remoteWfmService"  in connectionStrings.config  I gets error  "The entry 'remoteWfmService' has already been added".   Also instead forms.config we have sitecoreforms.config there already we have this setting <setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="web"/> Should I change DB name with master or Web is fine ?

Comment: @Shailesh: WFFM was changed in 8.0 update-3 (I think) to use the events table in Core database to pass data between CD and CM servers for Save Actions. You do not need to create this connection string in these versions.